# Sql Database server Remote access not working

Tags: sql-server

I am using windows server 2008 r2 and server has Private Ip. On server
I have configured Remote settings from TCP/IP with 1433 port and
Firewall is also disabled.

Can anybody tell me, Is there any other setting, I need to enable/disable?

== Edit ==
The error is:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

Comment: Have you looked on the connections tab of the properties dialogue?

Comment: I have done all required settings but still not able to connect.

Comment: @Chander.k, what you are getting error?

Comment: Have you try to this way ... servername\instance,1433

Comment: Yes, basically i am connecting sharepoint configuration manager  and getting error `An exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown.  Additional exception information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allo`

Comment: yes i have also tried with DNS

Comment: I am only able to ping to that server but not able to connect database server

Comment: @chander.k,This error usually means that the SQL Server computer can't be found or that the TCP port number is either not known, or is not the correct port number, or is blocked by a firewall. ref.http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

Comment: Can you open port via telnet? Can you add alias?

Comment: Maybe silly question, but have you restarted your service?

Comment: I have one more same server with same setting and it is working fine.I made clone from old server

Comment: I found the solution.There was problem with active directory.Port was blocked form the active directory.I have asked my client to open the port now I am able to connect

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you want to check is if Remote Connections are enabled on your SQL Server database.
right click the server… Go to properties  then Connections.

Under the hood of 'remote server connections' . It should be checked box tick of 'Allow remote connections to this server'

For further Ref [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/walzenbach/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: All settings which are required for remote connections are done but i am not able to connect

Comment: I found the solution.There was problem with active directory.Port was blocked form the active directory group policy.I have asked my client to open the port now I am able to connect